# How to find the cheapest traversal path with condition of passing certain nodes at least once

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory, dijkstra

I have a problem that sounds like this:

1. You're in a dangerous forest. Each path you take has a certain amount of risk associated with it every time you use it. (Unoriented graph with evaluated edges). Your task is to get from the entrance to the treasure cave, then escape through the exit (at a different place than the entrance)

For this I assume I need to use Dijkstra's algorithm for finding the cheapest path from A (start) to B, and then from B (trasure) to C (exit).

The second problem is what I don't know how to do though..

2. Consider the same problem, but there are 5 gems scattered on the crossroads (nodes) in the forest and there is a deadly wolf sleeping who will kill you if you collect a gem before slaying him first. You must collect all 5 before leaving the forest.

I'm not sure how to apply Dijkstra's algorithm to this. I know I first have to apply Dijsktra's algorithm to get to the wolf's node while pretending the nodes with gems and their edges don't exist, but then I'm not sure what's the least expensive path towards the B then C while also collecting all gems which may be on more expensive paths.

While I could run 5 instances of Dijsktra to get the cheapest path to each gem individually.. I realize there may be a situation where the sum of two cheapest paths to two gems might end up being more than just taking a shorter more expensive path to grab them both

Example (ignore the arrow):

[image: Unoriented graph]

If gem_1 resides at node 2, and gem_2 resides at node 1, and I would first find the cheapest path to gem_1, then to gem_2, it would be more expensive than to visit gem_2 before gem_1.

Will I have to do permutations of all orders of visiting the nodes and run Dijsktra iteratively for each different ordering of gems to collect? Or is there a better way? And are there any other things I should look out for?

Comment: Is this an exercise from an online judge ? Can you post the link so that we can validate our answers ? What are the constraints on the size of the problem instance ?

Comment: This is but sadly it is private and requires login which I cannot provide. This is also an edited version of the problem, only describing the important part that is the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's ignore the wolf fact as you know how to handle it and reformulate the problem in order to have more focus: you have a graph with a source and a destination and you must visit other five nodes (called gems).

So the first thing do is run a SSSP algorithm (let's say Dijkstra) from the source and from the gems, in this way you will have the minimum distance between the source, every gem and the destination.

In this way you can see a new fully connected graph where source, destination and gems are the nodes and the previously calculated distances are the edges weight. In this graph you have to explore every node with a starting one and an end one. I think this is a particular version of the travelling salesman problem, but you have only 7 nodes, so you can just try all the possibilities

Comment: This sounds right enough. So you're saying to just find the shortest path between all the nodes by running Dijkstra's algorithm and allowind the individual instances to "meet in the middle", and then try every possible permutation to see which order is the cheapest to visit them in?

Comment: @JackAvante  Yes, I'm saying exactly that

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following modeling:

1. As proposed by @Marco Zamboni, firstly find the wolf while regarding all edges to gems as non-existent.
2. Do a Dijkstra (start node: wolf, end node: exit) while disregarding all edges to exit as long as you have not collected all gems.

Would be nice if you could provide a graph for testing.